# How do I search a particular item in one textbox using PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, TABLE1 for parts and TABLE2 for vehicle application.

TABLE1

```
part_no | description | brand | price             
1234_AB | OIL SEAL | BRANDx | 97.50              
5678_CD | AIRCON FILTER | BRANDy | 400.00
```

TABLE2

```
part_no | make_name | name | year_model     
1234_AB | HONDA | LEGEND | 1991             
5678_CD | HONDA | PRELUDE | 1982       
1234_AB | HONDA | CIVIC | 1978          
5678_CD | HONDA | ACCORD | 1979
```

then I want to search this in 1 textbox:
      OIL FILTER HONDA CIVIC 1978
or CIVIC HONDA 1978 OIL FILTER
or 1978 HONDA CIVIC OIL FILTER

then it will show this result:

```
part_no | description | brand | price     
1234_AB | OIL SEAL | BRANDx | 97.50
```

Comment: please show what you have done so far ! a sample code would be nice.

Comment: that's going to be hard, it would be easier to make the one posting the search select,make,model,year etc

Answer (score 0):

Take the input from the textbox, split this with the " " (space) character and push to an array.

You should have created table entities so just loop through a comparison of each string value in the array to the entity properties.